# Какой тип шифрования уменьшает размер зашифрованного текста / бинарного файла

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Существуют ли такие типы шифрования текстов / бинарных файлов, которые уменьшают длину зашифрованного текста / размер зашифрованного бинарного файла? Есть, к примеру, текст из 1000 символов. Как его можно зашифровать так, чтобы в итоге его зашифрованная длина составляла, к примеру, 800 символов?

Comment: Это не шифр, а сжатие типа `Deflate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ни один алгоритм шифрования сам по себе не может уменьшить размер шифруемых данных - только оставить неизменными или увеличить.

Использование шифрования вместе со сжатием (архивированием) вроде бы может решить проблему, но... Ни один из алгоритмов сжатия не умеет гарантированно сжимать. Иными словами, для любого алгоритма сжатия существуют такие исходные данные, сжатие которых не изменит либо увеличит размер "сжатых" данных по сравнению с исходными.

Итого - не существует метода **гарантированно** уменьшить объём **произвольной** информации. Хоть с шифрованием, хоть без.

Answer (score 1):

Шифрование обычно приводит к увеличению размера файл. Но часто файл сжимают перед шифрованием, что бы усложнить анализ и взлом шифра.

Многие программы для шифрования сжимают файл, но пользователю об этом не говорят и поэтому на выходе может получаться файл меньшего размера.

Comment: Допустим. Как сжать файл можно?

Comment: Лучше задать новый вопрос

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613884/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81-jpeg-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE подойдёт?

Comment: Сжатие изображения без потери качества и сжатие произвольного файла - это совершенно разные алгоритмы. Если речь про произвольный файл, то лучше задать/поискать новый вопрос.

Comment: Сейчас разберусь.