# Как возможно уменьшить вес JPEG файла не утратив качество

Tags: java, сжатие, обработка-изображений

Есть картинка JPEG с разрешением 640x480. Вес файла 900 кБ. Теоретически, возможно ли уменьшить его размер, хотя бы, на 200-300 кБ не утратив качество? Существуют ли какие-либо способы сжатия таких графических файлов?

Речь идет о сжатии изображения средствами java.

Comment: imagecopyresampled ?

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, нет

Comment: есть какая-то функция в которой присутствует параметр "качество сжатия"  я забыл. сейчас вспомню. Она где-то в GD. В полученном файле мозно увидать текстовые строки что о создан ... и такое-то качество сжатия. Это вы ищете? У вас в вопросе только одна метка СЖАТИЕ. а конкретнее что вы имеет в виду?

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, извините, не понимаю о чём вы..

Comment: СЖАТИЕ в вебе? при работе с графическими редакторами? ГДЕ в какой отрасли вы применяете это СЖАТИЕ? Если не понимаете о чем я? - я умолкаю.

Comment: Java. Не веб, не PHP.

Comment: Теоретически возможно, если там есть лишние данные.

Comment: JPEG - уже сжат, сильнее его сжать без потерь качества практически невозможно.

Comment: `gzip -9` сжимает, но плохо (около 1%)

Comment: @avp, да, я пробовал. Даже чуть меньше процента - 0,6%